# How do I test an exception message containing localized dates in nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I've just come across an interesting problem with one of our unit tests. It's a case where we're trying to ensure that when a particular exceptional case is encountered, that we throw and provide a useful message to the handler - the idea is that the handler can just display (or log) that message directly. The problem is when the message contains a date - we want that date to be expressed using the users locale and any overrides that they may have specified on their local system.

The problem arises because we have two different CI infrastructures (don't ask - one development, one release) which for various reasons, actually have two (slightly) different date settings - one passes the test below, while the other uses a (customized) date format similar to "14Jan2014".

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException), ExpectedMessage="Invalid date: 14/01/2014")]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    var date = new DateTime(2014, 01, 14);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid date: " + date.ToString());
}
```

I am aware of the [SetCulture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setCulture&r=2.4.8) and [Culture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=culture&r=2.4.8) attributes but I don't believe these will work due to the customized aspect of the date format on the machine. Is it possible to somehow ignore the customised settings and at least use the locale's defaults for the purposes of the test?

Comment: Instead of using the ExpectedException attribute, why not rewrite your test to explicitly catch the exception and test the message?

Comment: Hmmm - good idea. Simply hadn't thought of it and was hoping to utilize the framework as much as possible.

Comment: Dave - if you put that up as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the ExpectedException attribute, rewrite your test to explicitly catch the exception and test the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly catch the exception as mentioned by @Dave Mackersie in his answer or you can use ExpectedException attribute with exception handler

```
[ExpectedException(Handler = "HandleException")]
```

Your test will be

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(Handler = "HandleException")]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    var date = new DateTime(2014, 01, 14);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid date: " + date.ToString());
}

public void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    if (!(ex is InvalidOperationException))
        Assert.Fail("Unexpected type of exception thrown by method");

    // Compare expected exception message with ex.Message
    // Assert.Fail if they do not match
}
```